# Vue.js trouble, cannot display array from axios.get

Tags: vue.js

I try to display info from GitHub issues. I use axios for GET from REST API. I try to get info for example from this https://api.github.com/repos/waffleio/waffle.io/issues

My .vue file:

```
<template>
    <h1>List</h1>
    <ul>{{ list }}</ul>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        data: function (){
            return {
                list: [],
            }
        },
        mounted: function () {
            console.log('List loaded');
            // fetch("https://api.github.com/repos/waffleio/waffle.io/issues")
            //     .then(response => response.json()).then((data) => {this.list = data;})
            this.fetchList();
        },
        methods: {
            fetchList: function () {
                console.log('List loading');
                    axios.get('https://api.github.com/repos/waffleio/waffle.io/issues')
                        .then((response) => {
                            console.log(response.data);
                            // this.list = response;
                            this.list = response.data;
                        }).catch((error) => {
                            console.log(error);
                        });
            },
        }
    }
</script>
```

I get blank page at chrome. But in browser console get this things:

> List loaded
>     app.js:43280 List loading
>     app.js:40402 Download the Vue Devtools extension for a better development experience:
>     https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools
>     app.js:40413 You are running Vue in development mode.
>     Make sure to turn on production mode when deploying for production.
>     See more tips at https://vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html
>     app.js:43282 (30) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
>     app.js:893 XHR finished loading: GET "https://api.github.com/repos/waffleio/waffle.io/issues".

I spend some hours at this problem. I try different examples, but still it dont working. Where I am doing mistakes? Why I cannot display data at {{list}}? I tried a v-for but it does not help. I am new on vuejs.

Comment: Your `<template>` should have only one root element (in your case you can wrap the `h1` and `ul` in a `div`); aren't you seeing any errors related to this, like _Component template should contain exactly one root element_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Vue.js, templates must have a [Single Root Element](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#A-Single-Root-Element). Because of this requirement, only your `h1` tag is being rendered. To fix this, you can wrap your template in its own `div`, like this:

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>List</h1>
        <ul>
            {{ list }}
        </ul>
    </div>
</template>
```

Using this, `list` will be rendered a string-representation of the array. As you suggested in your post, you'll be better off using `v-for` to create an individual `li` for each item in `list`.